# Is there a text editor that can convert Base 2 to hex?

Tags: text-editor, hex-viewer

E.g. I have a file with the following lines:

00000000000000000000000000001000,
00000000000000000000000000000000,
00000000000000000000000000010000,
00000000000000000000000000111000,
00000000000000000000000000110000,
00000000000000000000000001000000,

And I want to see them in hex representation:

0000_0008,
0000_0000,
0000_0010,
0000_0038,
0000_0030,
0000_0040,

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you code something, I suspect that you will have to convert each field individually.

Comment: Does it have to be a text editor? You save it as a CSV, import into Excel, convert using BIN2HEX, and export as CSV.

Comment: @browly, apparently BIN2HEX doesn't work for binary numbers with more than 10 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CudaText** editor has plugin. It reads current buffer as list of base-2 numbers, writes list of hex to a new tab.

- Download https://sourceforge.net/projects/cudatext/files/addons/plugins/plugin.Convert_base2_to_hex.zip/download
- Install: open ZIP in editor
- Call plugin in menu: "Plugins - Convert base-2 to hex".

Code of plugin in `__init__.py`

```
from cudatext import *

def do_fmt(n):
    s = '%08x'%n
    s = s[:4] + '_' + s[4:]
    return s

class Command:
    def run(self):
        s = ed.get_text_all()

        s = s.replace(' ', ',')
        s = s.replace(';', ',')
        s = s.replace('\n', ',')
        s = s.replace('\t', ',')
        l = s.split(',')

        l = [int(s, 2) for s in l if s]
        l = [do_fmt(n) for n in l]

        out = ', '.join(l)+','

        #put to new tab
        file_open('')
        ed.set_text_all(out)
```